# ggplot2: Issue with y-axis when generating graph with geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis, geom-col

I came back to R to make some graph for publication figure. However, I'm quite rusty and still in the learning process and I'm struggling on bar/col-based graph generation.

Context: Basically we have result of *in vitro* assays made with different type of cells from drifferent patients. The variable are the following:

- Patients
- Cell type
- Ratio (effector/responder cells, 1:3, 1:10 and 1:30)
- Cancer type

I would like to generate a graph were barplot represent the value of in vitro assay according to the dilution for one cell type/condition (1:3, 1:10, 1:30 for one condition, then 1:3, 1:10, 1:30 for a second, etc). A bit like this:

[exemple from publication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EslUn.png)

I've run the following code with a dummy data frame

```
df <- data.frame(
  Patient = rep(c("Ptn1", "Ptn2", "Ptn3"), each = 8),
  Cells = rep(rep(c("T1", "T2"), each = 3), 4),
  Ratio = rep(c("1:3", "1:10", "1:30"), 8),
  Value = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.9, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.15, 0.45, 0.85, 0.55, 0.85, 0.95, 0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9))

df$variable <- interaction(df$Cells, df$Ratio)
df$variable <- factor(df$variable, levels = c("T1.1:30", "T1.1:10", "T1.1:3", "T2.1:30", "T2.1:10", "T2.1:3"))
levels(df$variable)

ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = Value)) + geom_col()
```

Which gave me this graph:

[Dummy graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdnsA.png)

What is weird is that none of my value in df are above 1 (0.1 to 0.9) but y scale is giving value going up to 3 or 4. I have the same issue with the real dataset.

Also, what would be the elegant way to "gather" bar according to one condition/cell type and puting a small gap between cell type/condition?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geom_col()` doesn't compute any summary information, but instead leaves `y` as-is and then stacks the result. I think you might be looking for `geom_bar()` with `stat = "summary"`.

Moreover, [reconsider dynamite plots](https://simplystatistics.org/posts/2019-02-21-dynamite-plots-must-die/).

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  Patient = rep(c("Ptn1", "Ptn2", "Ptn3"), each = 8),
  Cells = rep(rep(c("T1", "T2"), each = 3), 4),
  Ratio = rep(c("1:3", "1:10", "1:30"), 8),
  Value = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.9, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.15, 0.45, 0.85, 0.55, 0.85, 0.95, 0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9))

df$variable <- interaction(df$Cells, df$Ratio)
df$variable <- factor(df$variable, levels = c("T1.1:30", "T1.1:10", "T1.1:3", "T2.1:30", "T2.1:10", "T2.1:3"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = Value)) +
  geom_errorbar(
    stat = "summary", 
    fun.data = ~ mean_sdl(.x, mult = 1),
    width = 0.2
  ) +
  geom_bar(
    stat = "summary", fun = mean
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. I'll check also your link about dynamite plot for sure. Actually I'm trying different ways to represents these data, to find the more suitable one :)